# how to locate path (mobile) c#

Tags: c#, windows-mobile

i was trying to locate specific path for a picture (that i want to include) in mobile application (web server).

and in terms of doing that i did this..

```
image src= \\program files\myprogram\a.jpg
```

is that how it works is mobile device?

to sum up, i was stuck being unable to display picture from specific path.

any help appreciated thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since the OS has no notion of a current directory, there is no Application.StartupPath. You can [use Reflection to locate where you are running from](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa457089.aspx).

Comment: thanks ctacke, i got it running. now it was simply the matter of ".//location/location.jpg"